# how to populate a list from a asp .net grid view?

Tags: c#, .net, list, gridview

I have a Grid View, I want to update all the rows that will be selected by checking the checkbook. First I want all the selected rows into a list. I don know how to do it. I know how to populate a grid from a list.
my grid view is

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridForResult" 
        Visible="true" 
        ShowHeader="false"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Height="22px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval( "TestRoll")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Height="22px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval( "Name")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-Height="22px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval( "Program")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-Height="22px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" Text="Selected" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My another problem is How to get only the selected (checkboxes) rows from the gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty straight forward if you are not paging your grid and you want to maintain checked value on PostBack.
On GridView Markup, set `DataKeyNames="{your primary key}"`

Code - behind

```
List<string> primaryKeys = new List<string>();
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridForResult.Rows)
{
    CheckBox check = row.FindControl("chkSelected") as CheckBox;
    if(check.Checked)
    {
        primaryKeys.Add(GridForResult.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

The `List<string>` **primaryKeys** will now hold all the *checked* primary keys.

Comment: Here, TestRoll is my primary key. But when I am writing like primaryKeys.Add(GridForResult.DataKeys["TestRoll"].Value.ToString()); It is Giving me an error :Argument type 'string' is not assignable to parameter type int, can you please solve this probelm?

Comment: This Problem can be solved by placing an integer as an index of Datakeys i.e. primaryKeys.Add(GridForResult.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString()); where index is an int type variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> objList = new List<string>();        

foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
      objList.Add(row["id"].Text);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the checkboxes column a TemplateColumn. Then on postback you need to iterate the GridView Rows Collection and do something like this:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gridViewId)
{
    CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("CheckBoxId") as CheckBox;//use chk value as needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare a collection of say string type,
List<string> objList = new List<string>();

foreach(GridViewRow row in gridViewId)
{
    CheckBox chk = row.FindControl("CheckBoxId") as CheckBox;
    if(chk.IsChecked)
    {
     objList.Add(row["id"].Text);
    }
}
save this list in session,
Session["checkedList"] = objList;

when you want to retireve,use,
objList = List<string>(Session["checkedList"]);
```